# Are .select and or .where responsible for causing N+1 queries in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two methods here, distinct_question_ids and @correct_on_first attempt. The goal is to show a user how many distinct multiple choice questions have been answered that are correct.

The second one will let me know how many of these distinct MCQs have been answered correctly on the first attempt. (A user can attempt a MCQ many times)

Now, when a user answers thousands of questions and has thousands of user answers, the page to show their performance is taking 30 seconds to a minute to load. And I believe it's due to the .select method, but I don't know how to replace .select without using .select, since it loops just like .each

Is there any method that doesn't cause N+1?

```
distinct_question_ids = @user.user_answers.includes(:multiple_choice_question).
  where(is_correct_answer: true).
  distinct.pluck(:multiple_choice_question_id)

@correct_on_first_attempt = distinct_question_ids.select { |qid|
  @user.user_answers.
    where(multiple_choice_question_id: qid).first.is_correct_answer
}.count
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.pluck` returns an Array of values, not an ActiveRecord::Relation.

So when you do `distinct_question_ids.select` you're not calling ActiveRecord's `select`, but Array's `select`. Within that select, you're issuing a fresh new query against @user for every id you just plucked -- including ones that get rejected in the select.

You could create a query named `distinct_questions` that returns a relation (no pluck!), and then build `correct_on_first_attempt` off of that, and I think you'll avoid the N+1 queries.

Something along these lines:

```
class UserAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :distinct_correct, -> { includes(:multiple_choice_question)
                                   .where(is_correct_answer: true).distinct }

   scope :first_attempt_correct, -> { distinct_correct
                                        .first.is_correct_answer }
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def good_guess_count
    @correct_on_first_attempt = @user.user_answers.distinct_correct.first_attempt_correct.count
  end
end
```

You'll need to ensure that .first is actually getting their first attempt, probably by sorting by id or created_at.

As an aside, if you track the attempt number explicitly in UserAnswer, you can really tighten this up:

```
class UserAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :correct, -> { where(is_correct_answer: true) }
  scope :first_attempt, -> { where(attempt: 1) }
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def lucky_guess_count
    @correct_on_first_attempt = @user.user_answers.includes(:multiple_choice_question)
                                     .correct.first_attempt.count
  end
end
```

If you don't have an attempt number in your schema, you could .order and .group to get something similar. But...it seems that some of your project requirements depend on that sequence number, so I'd recommend adding it if you don't have it already.

ps. For fighting N+1 queries, use gem bullet. It is on-point.